What is the function of the ~/Library/Daemon Containers directory?
On my macOS 15.1 system, I have a mystery directory at ~/Library/Daemon Containers
This directory is about 300MB in size, the largest of which appears to contain copies of all the iOS apps installed on my iPhone. Here's a screenshot that shows an example of this in DaisyDisk.app:

Is there a documented purpose for this folder, and can it be safely purged as part of routine maintenance?

Related question that does not answer this one directly: What's the purpose of ~/Library/Containers?


Just guessing, but I'm assuming that these are the sandbox folders for Daemons. A Daemon is a program or process that runs in the background but remains inactive until invoked. It is usually a process or a running program that does not have a direct interface.
